# How to get frames count of a video file with EmguCV?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using the below code to get all the frames from a video file. However, when I run the code for a sample video, `double FramesCount` is  `1402402` and pops an error on frame # `467`.

**P.S** I think the real frames count is around ~467 since the video file is only 15 seconds (15sec * 30fps = ~450 frames)

```
_capture = new Capture(OpenFile.FileName);
FramesCount = (int)_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

for(int i = 0; i < FramesCount - 1; i++)
{
    FramesArray.Add(_capture.QueryGrayFrame().Resize(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR));
}
```

How can I get the exact frames count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code:

```
int framecount = (int)Math.Floor(capt.GetCaptureProperty(CapProp.FrameCount)); //get count of frames   
double framerate = capt.GetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Fps); //get fps
```

works fine for me if still relevant. I have like 21,6666667 secs video and it return me right count of frames.

Comment: In my case (OP), `FramesCount` was very high, but I execute the loop anyway and I populate as much `QueryGrayFrame` as possible into `FramesArray`, and once it pops an error (no frames anymore but loop is still going since FramesCount was higher than actual frames), I just ignore it and proceed to use `FramesArray` which has all frames of the video.